# Javascript in knockout css binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I'm trying to apply a css class to a navigation bar panel if the current page URL is the URL of what the panel points to.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" 
     data-bind="css: {'test-class': window.location === My.Constants.appRoot 
                                    + '/thispage'}">
```

This binding doesn't seem to work. Anyone have ideas on whether or not this should work? Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in the console? It's hard to say what's wrong without more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `window.location.href`.

http://jsfiddle.net/zTK2q/2/

Comment: As a note if you are updating the class based on the URL but are only using hash routing or something this will not be notified